# Remember the last settings of expandable/collapsible navigation area

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF query using the MVVM pattern. The first panel is a navigation area and the second panel is a tab area. Between both is the navigation button. If I click on the navigation button, then it will collapse the navigation area. If I again click this button again, then both the panels are visible.

So all I want to do is have their final state persist through application shutdowns. If the user collapses the navigation area, and closes the application, then next time they open the application, the navigation area should still be closed. I don't want to have to store this information in a DataBase.

How can I achieve this?

The sample look and feel of the image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM than you have a ViewModel for that View.

In that ViewModel you should have a command that will be executed when user clicks on Navigation button, so that you can decide what to do with Navigation Area

So basically you could store that info (is Navigation collapsed or not) in Application.Properties.Settings, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

There you create property, e.g. IsNavigationAreaCollapsed of type boolean.

And when command is executed in code do this:

```
    private void OnNavigationButtonExecution()
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.IsNavigationAreaCollapsed = !Properties.Settings.Default.IsNavigationAreaCollapsed
        CollapseNavigationArea(Properties.Settings.Default.IsNavigationAreaCollapsed); // this will collapse or not the navoigation area
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); //save settings, so that it will be stored when app shutsdown
    }
```

and in ViewModel constructor add code that will read a value from settings (Properties.Settings.Default.IsNavigationAreaCollapsed) and do this

```
    CollapseNavigationArea(Properties.Settings.Default.IsNavigationAreaCollapsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one easy way of implementing it.
What I did is created an XML file (outside Bin folder obviously)
passed a default value for grid width to the XML file.

The function which is getting called at the application start I retrieved the value of Grid Width which I set default in XML file(for the first time I am passing a default value) with help of Linq To XML and stored this entry into a variable.

Now,I am passing this variable for Grid length.
Now, if the user collapse/expand the panel and closes the application then simply on Close function I am updating the value of XML.